# Multiple statements in Main module

Tags: syntax-error, elm

How do you put multiple lines of statements inside an Elm main module

Example,

```
module Main exposing (main)
import Html exposing (text)

main =
  text "1"
  text "2"
```

The above does not work and gives this error

```
Detected errors in 1 module.
-- TOO MANY ARGS -------------------------------------------------- src/Main.elm

The `text` function expects 1 argument, but it got 3 instead.

5|>  text "1"
6|   text "2"

Are there any missing commas? Or missing parentheses?
```

Putting parenthesis and commas does not help.

Comment: Is this the entire module content? If not, can you post it please?

Comment: @0xc14m1z I edited with complete code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Elm is an expression-based language. It doesn't have statements because it doesn't have side-effects. Instead it consists of expressions which return values associated with types that are verified at compile-time.

Your code is a valid expression syntactically, so I'm not sure how you got that specific error. I can't reproduce it either directly at top level, where expressions don't belong, or in a function where expressions do belong, but there I get a type error instead of a syntax error. You're leaving out some essential part of your code.

In any case, even if you put it correctly into a function this won't do what you want. There are multiple problems even then:

1. Your code will be interpreted as three arguments applied to the function `text`, `'1'`, `text`, and `'2'`, because the line-break is not significant.
2. `'1'` is a character literal, not a string literal. `"1"` is a string literal.
3. Whatever you're going to use this with, it most likely expects a single element, not a list of elements.

The correct way to return two elements as one is to wrap the two elements in a parent element, like 'span' for example:

```elm
module Main exposing (main)

import Html exposing (text, span)

main =
    span []
        [ text "1"
        , text "2"
        ]
```

Lastly, I recommend that you begin learning by following [the official Elm guide](https://guide.elm-lang.org/). Elm is different enough that a trial-and-error approach based on what tends to work in JavaScript is likely to just lead to frustration.

Comment: text is in fact expecting a string so I change my code and edited my question with the complete code and corresponding error.

Comment: Alright, then putting the two `text` elements wrapped in a `span` into `main` is all you need to do. I've updated the answer to show a full working example.